# Jenkins - Cascading Plugin - Auto evaluate not happening to second level

Tags: dynamic, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins, cascade

In Jenkins one can use Cascading Dynamic Choice parameter plugin i.e. if paramter1 is a a simple choice parameter (lets say parameter name is **targetEnv**) with choice values being *int, qa, int-test etc* per line and if I select the value 'int', then I can use Cascading Dynamic Choice parameter to tweak the target values of my second parameter for ex: **targetEnvServer** to anything at runtime which I'll set for that 'int' environment only.

This is useful as if a user selects any other environment "qa" for ex, then the value of *targetEnvServer* parameter will change automatically as soon as the selection in the first parameter (choice parameter) changes from int to something else. All we need to make sure is, the Groovy piece for returning a valid value (list) is written in the Groovy code section of Cascading Dynamic Choice Parameter plugin's configuration for that user selected environment in *targetEnv* parameter.

For this first and second variable (where second variable's value depends upon the value of first parameter's value) **is working fine**!, **BUT** it is **NOT** working if there's also a 3rd parameter (of type *Cascading Dynamic Choice Parameter plugin* where the parent parameter **is also a** Cascading Dynamic Choice Parameter type) for ex: **restoreDateTime2** which is dependent upon the 2nd parameter (which was again dependent upon paramter1 *targetEnv* and was a *Cascading Dynamic Choice Parameter plugin* type).

This image shows the jenkins job configuration:
[image]

This image shows what happens when you click on Build with parameters and an error comes. **ERROR: Structured Form Element Not Found: someVariable**

[image]

This image shows what happens when you change the selection from one value to other for first parameter

[image]

How can I achieve cascading dynamic choice parameter behavior which is happening successfully between parameter1 and parameter2 ... for parameter3 as well (when parameter2 value is changing due to any change in selection for parameter1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jenkins [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) I was able to achieve what I was looking for but the issue with Cascading Choice plugin still exists.

Active choices plugin supports 3 parameter types and does support multilevel reference variables to populate variable's values (where a parameter is dependent upon another / reference parameter). Documentation available on Jenkins plugin's site for Active Choices plugin is good enough to try the above mentioned scenario I had and it worked well.

I had to write a small Groovy piece of code to fetch the data after using the reference variable and using that to fetch some data from either on Jenkins master / a remote machine folder.